# LDAP configuration for Mac server

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, openldap

We just migrated our php webapps to a new web server (Mac OS X 10.9.5). We are having trouble with ldap logins to the webapps. We are able to successfully connect to a remote ldap server, but when we try and ldap_bind(), it is unable to bind. We haven't changed the code from what worked on the old webserver, so I think it has something to do with the openLDAP configuration on our new server. I compared `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` on the old and new servers, and I saw that the `TLS_REQCERT` attribute was set to `demand` on the new server, but it was set to `never` on the old server.

I was sure this was the problem, since we didn't have any certs installed to the proper directory in `/etc/openldap/certs`, but for a sanity check, I changed `demand` to `never`, restarted the mac, and the problem persisted.

Any thoughts as to what I can do to troubleshoot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a bit of troubleshooting, I found out that there was a conflicting ldap.config file in `/opt/local/etc/openldap/`. I guess that was added when I used macports to install php53-ldap. I ended up symlinking `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` to the `/opt/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf` file and it worked.